# Uninstalling the GWT from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gwt

<strike>I installed Eclipse indigo 3.7 and then GWT. Other day I deleted Eclipse because I had 2 of them and I confounded them. 
I downloaded the Eclipse again and I tried to reinstall GWT, but no success: log errors. Tried to uninstall GWT from Help->Install new software-> "Already installed". Still no success (and this time Eclipse is installed in other path)</strike>

A little help, please?
already tried restart

THANKS ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the GWT FAQ I have read: **If you uninstall the plugin, you will have to uninstall the bundled SDKs first, which is done from the same dialog.**

I have also read that **they are still available on disk, and they can be enabled at any time in the future. To physically remove the feature and its plug-ins, you will have to manually remove the feature from the eclipse/features directory and its plug-ins from the eclipse/plugins directory.** Here is more info that: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F